# How can I pick up the error type from a promise?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services

I use the `promise` method in my code.

```
  try {
    const preSecret = await secretManager.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretId }).promise();
    const preSecretString = preSecret.SecretString;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code !== 'ResourceNotFoundException') {
      throw (err);
    }
  }
```

When I hover over the promise method I can see that it has the type `Promise<PromiseResult<AWS.SecretsManager.GetSecretValueResponse, AWS.AWSError>>`.

But the `err` in the catch block has type `unknown`.

How can I get TypeScript to pick up the type of the error?

Comment: With Promises you shouldn't be using try-catch but `.then` and `.catch`, no? See https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling

Comment: @Inigo: OP has `await`ed on the function that returns a promise so can use a try...catch statement

Comment: @Wing See [Promise-based functions should not throw exceptions](https://2ality.com/2016/03/promise-rejections-vs-exceptions.html) and [Error handling with promises](https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling) and [Promises and Error Handling](https://making.change.org/post/69613524472/promises-and-error-handling) and MANY MORE articles on the web on this topic.

Comment: @Inigo: sorry, what's that got to do with anything? OP's promise likely does reject, it doesn't throw. But when you await a promise that rejects, the argument passed to the reject function will be thrown (see [await promise rejection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#promise_rejection)). You can then catch this like any other exception with a try...catch.

Comment: @Inigo: I have a feeling you're not understanding [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: @Wing read the very next section in your link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239961/discussion-between-wing-and-inigo).

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

TypeScript types the exception variable of the `catch` block as `unknown` because that's the most type safe way as the type of whatever is thrown is unknown given it's possible to throw any valid JavaScript expression. However there are discussions about improving this, see [TypeScript#13219](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219) as one example.

## Solution

You'll have to help TypeScript to narrow the error type. Here are two possible methods:

### `instanceof` narrowing

If you have access to the underlying error class you could narrow by checking if the error is an instance of such class.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  foo: string;

  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "CustomError";
    this.foo = "foo";
  }
}

function foo() {}

try {
  foo();
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof CustomError)  {
    console.log(error);
    //          ^^^^^
    //        Hover here
    // `var error: CustomError` should appear
    // `error` has been narrowed to `CustomError`
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZV6ApgB5IEB2AJjNrvgN4CwAUNNAGYooBc0yWAlmQDmAbmbNWwFGT7xgqLAAo0BKGCEEefQUICU0Ri1a94ABwJKVajbrFHWSABb8IAOjJgV0ALzQARAjI6DR4fnbG0E4urhwoPv6xYRLQAL7MaUzMbPBk8vzS7JyK+nQZzEhYAJ4GybHFdinQwGBIwI7Qiha0Jcn8bB1deNCCyGC5BCj9gaiYOHj6NfZN0hAoIASuIChCnXNYtsmsAPRHEWfQAHpXV4fQJ+esABIoAG4W0I4WBLf3AAYvYHwgywPGmwT2v14jhQ8BAFGgYFM5kBP1Ov2BkMckGgACMCORoB45gB3Ajw1DQX5g2a0X7JDIZIA)

### Type predicate and `in` operator narrowing

You could check for the existence of various properties that your error should have (the [duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) ) through a type predicate.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  foo: string;

  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "CustomError";
    this.foo = "foo";
  }
}

function foo() {}

function isCustomError(error: any): error is CustomError {
  return "foo" in error;
}

try {
  foo();
} catch (error) {
  if (isCustomError(error)) {
    console.log(error);
    //          ^^^^^
    //        Hover here
    // `var error: CustomError` should appear
    // `error` has been narrowed to `CustomError`
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCuEAuB7AtgUQE5ZV6ApgB5IEB2AJjNrvgN4CwAUNNAGYooBc0yWAlmQDmAbmbNWwFGT7xgqLAAo0BKGCEEefQUICU0Ri1a94ABwJKVajbrFHWSABb8IAOjJgV0ALzQARAjI6DR4fnbG0E4urhwoPv6xYRLQAL7MaUzMbPBk8vzS7JyK+nQZWTl5BS6BqJg4eIoWtDxgZACeujxNeNAucIi1IfTJWARI8FhkCZx+vVPdWHZlTEhYbQbJscVL0MBgSMCO0I31WCXJ-GzH1QPBpye0uuf2u9IQKCAEriAoQg94tmSrAA9MCIuDoAA9aHQoHQUEQ1gACRQADcLNBHBYCHCEQADVFgfALHg1O60PG8RwoeAgCjQMCmcxE3FgvELSmOSDQABGBHI0A89QA7gR6ahoHiyXUKckMikgA)

## Further reading

- [`in` operator narrowing, TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing)
- [`instanceof` narrowing, TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing)
- [Type predicates, TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)
- [Type narrowing, TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)